# upgrade btrfs without upgrading kernel?

Tags: btrfs

We're running ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS with 3.13.0-38-generic kernel and btrfs v3.12
I've read that a min version for btrfs of 3.14 is desirable. Due to one of our programs integrating with kernel we are unable to upgrade to a later kernel or version of ubuntu.
Is it possible to upgrade btrfs outside of an ubuntu upgrade?

Comment: This question needs additional information: What specific features that you need are in btrfs 3.14 but aren't in 3.12?  If they are bug fixes, are you sure they haven't been incorporated into Ubuntu's version of 3.12 already?  You know that Ubuntu's version will be well-tested whereas if you try and compile a kernel/kernel module yourself it won't be well-tested code.

Comment: Nothing specific.  Yesterday I had a driver/kernel crash followed by a power cycle.  FS was corrupted, box was unable to boot, grub2 couldn't find /@/boot.  This is a production box, so i was hoping for btrfs to be more resilient.

Comment: there is not a single "btrfs 3.14" - there is a kernel module, that has to be updated by compiling a custom kernel. and then there are the utilities. If 3.14 is not available in a ppa or the ubuntu repositories, you have to find and compile the package manually. The first step is to identify what you need , then try to find it in a .deb